# What is the easiest/lightest way to parse user agents for purely Windows, Mac, or Other?

Tags: php, regex, logging, browser, user-agent

I've been investigating various user agent parsers and have been surprised at the complexity and size required.

If I'm **only** interested in parsing for the OS into three categories: `Windows`, `Mac`, or `Other` — how can I do this efficiently, lightly, and quickly?

I don't care about browsers, versions, or anything else.  Just Mac, Windows or Other.

What do you recommend?

Here's what I have so far:

```
if (strpos($user_agent, 'Windows')) $os = 'Windows';
elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Macintosh')) $os = 'Macintosh';
else $os = 'Other';
```

Any danger in this straight forward approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be enough. Older Windows versions tend to have `WinNT` prefix instead. Looking for `Win` only also match non-windows user agents. Also for Macintosh, search for `Mac` only. Usually it is listed as Mac OS in user agents.

This is a good reg exp for Windows detection:

```
/Win(?:dows )?([^do]{2})\s?(\d+\.\d+)?/
```